# Show labels outside in sunburst highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show the labels in last level (which is 3) in Sunburst Highchart outside . Is it possible to achieve? . I tried using distance parameter and many more methods, but it didn't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the sunburst doesn't have implement this logic which pie has. I recommend using [dataLabels.rotation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.data.dataLabels.rotation) as a solution to set datalabels.

```
dataLabels: {
  y: -75,
  rotation: 0,
  x: -15,
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/akryx2o7/3/

Comment: Cool.  It worked !!